# Javascript convert multidimentional array to indexes

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, indexing

My script working just fine but I don't know why there is an inner voice inside my head that tells me that there must be an 'Inside the box' solution instead of writing a function or a much simpler way to get what I want.

All I want is to get the array indexes (not keys) instead of the values.

Here is my simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>&nbsp;</title>
<style></style>
</head>
<body>

<script>

function arrayIndexes(arrConvert)
{

    var newArr=[];

    for(y in arrConvert)
    {
        newArr[y]=[];
        for(x in arrConvert[y])
        {
            newArr[y][x]=parseInt(x);
        }
    }
    
    return newArr;

}

var menu=
[
    ['Spaghetti','Pizza','Lazanya'],
    ['Vinaigrette','Mushroom','Ketchup'],
    ['Bon Appétit'],
    ['Steve Vai','Joe Satriani','Hezi Gangina','Nuno Bettencourt']
];

console.table(arrayIndexes(menu));

</script>
</body>
```

Is there any magic trick to replace the function with 'inTheBox' javascript solution or some other smoother way? I want to make it as clean as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array **map** method, **spread syntax** and **keys** method to do your job. Traverse the array of arrays and get all the indexes and map it.

```js
const menu = [
  ['Spaghetti', 'Pizza', 'Lazanya'],
  ['Vinaigrette', 'Mushroom', 'Ketchup'],
  ['Bon Appétit'],
  ['Steve Vai', 'Joe Satriani', 'Hezi Gangina', 'Nuno Bettencourt'],
];

const arrayIndexes = (arrConvert) => arrConvert.map((x) => [...x.keys()]);

console.log(arrayIndexes(menu));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const menu = [
  ["Spaghetti", "Pizza", "Lazanya"],
  ["Vinaigrette", "Mushroom", "Ketchup"],
  ["Bon Appétit"],
  ["Steve Vai", "Joe Satriani", "Hezi Gangina", "Nuno Bettencourt"],
];

const sol = menu.map(arr => [arr.map((_, i) => i)]).flat();

//console.table(sol);
console.log(sol);
```